# Generating Access token with axios in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

[POSTMAN sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS3PQ.png)

the same process i want to do it in react-native and i have tried like that

```
var baseHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret)
  };

var params = {
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret,
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
}

axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "http://transrv02-ap01.transsyssolutions.com:8080/apex/apxprd/oauth/token",
      headers: baseHeaders,  
      body:params      
    })
      .then((responseJson) => {  console.log("clientid---"+responseJson)})
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

but it have showing 401 error. 
Anyone can help me!
thanks in advance....

Comment: var params = {
   " client_id": client_id,
   " client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
}

Comment: i have removed auth header but didn't work...and thanks for the security tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Found My own way not in axios

```js
var baseHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(client_id + ":" + client_secret)
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(baseHeaders) + "baseHeaders")

var params = "grant_type=client_credentials";

console.log(JSON.stringify(params) + "params")

return fetch('http://apex/apxprd/oauth/token',{
  method: "POST",
  body: params,
  headers: baseHeaders
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responsetokenJson) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(responsetokenJson) + "responseJsonclientid")
  var token = responsetokenJson.access_token
  console.log("this.props.tokens--" + token)

  this.setState({
    accessToken: token
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
axios.post('http://transrv02-ap01.transsyssolutions.com:8080/apex/apxprd/oauth/token',
    params,
    {
      headers: baseHeaders
    })
  .then((responseJson) => {  console.log("clientid---"+responseJson)})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: yes and its working fine but i want to generate in code way

Comment: Check the network in your inspect elements of your browser... and post the response details in the question

Comment: Have you enabled the browser debugging in the particular device/emulator?

Comment: yes i'm debugging it but it was not showing in network. it showing details onlu in console

Comment: Run code again immediately check the network tab, then you will see